# When searching in the start menu, show more than 3 matching programs

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I usually search in there for programs, and files elsewhere, so for example, if I want to update windows, I'll type in update, but it only comes up with apple, desura and java, so I need to click the programs option to view the remaining two.

I know it's hardly the end of the world, but does anyone know how to increase this amount? It's just a bit annoying considering it's only the programs I really want, and it doesn't order them by usage, so no matter how many times I do it, it'll still keep the same programs at the top